# How to fetch data from database and print it on a table in moodle 3.7.2?

Tags: database, moodle

I am new to Moodle and the documented APIs are not helping me at all. Can someone please help me?  I am trying to fetch data from the database and show it on screen.
Is there any tutorial or anything that can help me understand Moodle easily?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming what you want is a report generation tool.  This will allow you to input a SQL query and get back a report of the results. 
 I would recommend going to this link and installing this plugin into your site. https://moodle.org/plugins/block_configurable_reports

Once you have that installed you can look over its documentation at this link.  It should have everything you need to at least get started.
https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/Configurable_reports